# How to save or copy in the clipboard a graph made with Statet/R/Eclipse?

Tags: r, graphics, graph, statet

My setup: **Eclipse**,  **R** and **Statet**

I am using R from inside Eclipse using Statet.

I have made a graph (this is the plot of a time series, in case this is relevant information).

I now wish to save this graph as a JPG image (or BMP, or the like ...), or to copy this image in the clipboard. I need my graph in a PowerPoint presentation.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jpeg('foo.png')` more help is available by typing `?jpeg` at the statet prompt. You may also be able to write to the clipboard, using a destination of `clipboard` instead of the filename, depending on your platform -- see `?connections` for further details.

Comment: thanks a lot. besides, i haven't found anything relevant in the documentation for copying and then pasting out of Statet/Eclipse